# Corona SDK - google play game services crashing on production version

Tags: android, google-play, coronasdk, google-play-games

my leaderboards etc were working but when I download a production version of my app and go to my leaderboards it crashes.

I sent myself a copy of the crash report and i get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
at CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google.GameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn(GameHelper.java:348)
at CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google.LuaLoader$3.run(LuaLoader.java:192)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

How do i add that into my build.settings in Corona SDK.

my build.settings

```
  plugins =
    {
        ["plugin.bit"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
        },
        ["CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.apple"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { iphone=true, ["iphone-sim"]=true }
        },  
        ["CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { android=true }
        },              
    }, 



android =
{
    googlePlayGamesAppId = "11111",
    usesPermissions =
    {
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
    },
},
```

if e.type == "applicationStart" then
    print("i startedz!!")

```
local function callback(e)
    print("init called")
end
gameNetwork.init("google", callback)
```

"i startedz" is being printed but i'm never entering the callback function?  this was working just yesterday!  what happened here!

Comment: Did you follow all these steps? https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/06/25/tutorial-introducing-google-play-game-services/

Comment: the issue was on coronas side..  rebuilt the next day and it worked